# http-proxy-middleware: accessing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, causing ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, webpack, http-proxy-middleware

Using webpack2 to compile on the fly an angular application, I configured `devServer` this way:

```
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:52163'
    }
}
```

The target of the proxy is a IIS Express server. After upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to 2017, I now get the error `ECONNREFUSED` when trying to access `/api`.

I changed `http-proxy-middleware` to get more information about the error and noticed it tries to connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

How can I ensure `http-proxy-middleware` connects to `localhost` ?

Thanks